# После выгрузки плагина не освобождается dll из AssemblyLoadContext

Tags: c#, dll, assembly, newtonsoft.json

За основу взят пример с github dotnet https://github.com/dotnet/samples/blob/main/core/tutorials/Unloading/Host/Program.cs, однако метод `GetMessage()` из PluginClass был переработан, возвращает `Task<string>`, имеет следующее тело:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
    var models = doc.RootElement.EnumerateArray().Select(element => new Model
        {
            UserId = element.GetProperty("userId").GetInt32(), 
            Id = element.GetProperty("id").GetInt32(), 
            Title = element.GetProperty("title").GetString(), 
            Body = element.GetProperty("body").GetString()
        }).ToList();
}

return "Hello from the unloadable plugin";
```

Этот код прекрасно работает и Assembly выгружается после вызова `Unload()` у AssemblyLoadContext. Однако если использовать System.Text.Json или Newtonsoft.Json, то dll не собирается выгружаться из контекста, как долго я бы ни ждал (я пробовал вплоть до 100 секунд и это сильно запредельное время в моих условиях использования).

Пример проблемного кода с использование System.Text.Json ниже:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var models = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Model>>(responseContent, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
}

return "Hello from the unloadable plugin";
```

Пример проблемного кода с использование Newtonsoft.Json ниже:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var models = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model>>(responseContent);
}

return "Hello from the unloadable plugin";
```

Как считаете, с чем данное поведение связано и можно ли его каким-либо образом избежать?

Comment: Когда System.Text.Json используете, удаляете ли пакет Newtonsoft из сборки? `Model` где находится, в сборке или за пределами? JsonDocument - это что такое? Из какой сборки? В угадайку будем играть?

Comment: Когда использую System.Text.Json, то пакет, разумеется, удаляю. Model находится в сборке плагина и, как видно, никуда её не покидает. JsonDocument также из System.Text.Json с одним лишь важным отличием -- явно не приводит к типу Model (только к JsonDocument, https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-8.0), а занимается разбиением json-файла по root'ам.

Comment: а если шорткатом `await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Model>>(url)`?

Comment: Мысль интересная, но, к сожалению, не помогла.

Comment: версия .NET какая? если меньше, чем 8, попробуйте 8. Там сериализация без рефлексии возможна. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/source-generation

Comment: Вариант решения для System.Text.Json приложил в ответах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спустя некоторое время мне удалось разобраться в проблеме в контексте `System.Text.Json` (что в моём случае абсолютно устраивает меня).

Для рефлексии при работе с типами пользователя создаются долгоживущие экземпляры `JsonSerializerOptions` (скорее всего под этим подразумевается кэш опций, подробнее [здесь](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/65323)).

Для решения данной проблемы предусмотрен метод `ClearCache()` в классе `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptionsUpdateHandler`. Иначе говоря, в сборке `Host` (на основе примера из `dotnet/samples` из вопроса), где мы подключаем плагин, перед `Unload()` достаточно добавить следующее, и проблема уйдет:

```
var assembly = typeof(JsonSerializerOptions).Assembly;
var updateHandlerType = assembly.GetType("System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptionsUpdateHandler");
var clearCacheMethod = updateHandlerType?.GetMethod("ClearCache", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
clearCacheMethod?.Invoke(null, new object?[] { null });
```